# Убивает процесс во время чтения и записи файла Python

Tags: python, filestream, str-replace, kill

Есть функция которая заменяет нужные символы в файле (файл 10 гигабайт +- 5гб), написана она так:

```
def replace_in_file(replacements, path_to_file, encoding='utf-8'):
    file_name = os.path.basename(path_to_file)
    temp_path = f'{path_to_file[:-len(file_name)]}{datetime.now().timestamp()}_{file_name}'
    with open(path_to_file, 'r', encoding=encoding, buffering=8192) as file_from:
        with open(temp_path, 'w', encoding=encoding, buffering=8192) as file_to:
            for line in file_from:
                for from_, to_ in replacements.items():
                    line = line.replace(from_, to_)
                file_to.write(line)
    os.remove(path_to_file)
    os.rename(temp_path, path_to_file)
```

Когда локально запускаю программу, то она спокойно работает, суммарно занимая не больше полтора гигабайта в памяти. Но всё почему-то работает иначе на сервере с убунтой.

Делал и без `buffering`, результат такой-же. Там, как я выяснил опытным путём, процесс замены строк сжирает до 15 гигабайт памяти и убивается. Подскажите пожалуйста, что я мог тут упустить?

**UPD:**
Дело тут в чтении файла. Пробовал разные способы, с readline и с помощью генератора, ничего не помогает, на третьей итерации процесс умирает.

Comment: Попробуйте считывать файл посточно с помощью `readline`. [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)

Comment: Посмотрите тему https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16669428/process-very-large-20gb-text-file-line-by-line/16669683#16669683

Comment: @5c0rp Пробовал, всё рушится на третьей строке при чтении файла. Но на локальной машине windows, всё работает отлично

Comment: @AndyPavlov ничего из этого не помогло

Comment: А много ли самих `replacements`?

Comment: @CrazyElf, нет, всего два

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помогло чтение файла кусками, а не построчно:

```
with open(path_to_file, 'r', encoding=encoding) as source, open(temp_path, 'w', encoding=encoding) as output:
    while line := source.read(chunk_size):
            ...
```

Но тут надо учитывать то, что часть заменяемого слова может быть разбита в несколько чанков(в зависимости от размера чанков и заменяемых слов). Это имплементируйте уже на свой вкус и цвет)